# How to return only first result using @Query notation?

Tags: jpql, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I am making a query using a method defined through the @Query annotation in the Spring Framework.

```
@Transactional(readOnly=true)
@Query("SELECT x FROM X x ORDER BY x.id ASC")
List<X> findLowest();
```

I am currently returning a list of items, but I really only want to return the first one.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

First, you should add a Pageable object to your method like this:

```
@Transactional(readOnly=true)
@Query("SELECT x FROM X x ORDER BY x.id ASC")
List<X> findLowest(Pageable pageable);
```

and to use in this way:

```
Pageable firstResult = new PageRequest(0, 1);
List<X> result = repository.findLowest(firstResult);
```

In this way, you can reuse this method another time.